# Credit Card Payment accepted But no Order in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I've have a few small instances where payment was collected in auth net but no order shows up in magento ?

I've searched for similar issues but nothing very informative.

Anyone else ran into this ?

Comment: Check if there are errors in `var/log/exception.log` that could prevent the checkout process from working correctly (assuming that you have logging enabled - if not enable it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have been occurred in the code folder. First of all have you override or overwrite the "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid"? Because this file is responsible for displaying the order grid. If not your core file may have got corrupted. Try replacing the "Sales" folder from any other installation and check whether the problem is resolved.

If that doesnot resolve the issue than you must have overiden or overwritten the file.

First try the above solution and tell if it works or not.

Hope this will work